# Dynamically add a new key and value to a global object in chrome extension pop up

Tags: google-chrome-extension, javascript-objects

I'm relatively new to objects in javascript. Currently I'm making a chrome extension where, in the background script, there is a counter that updates. In my popup file, I have a global variable that reads the background scripts counter and updates a variable in the popup file. Then I have a text analyzer that generates a number every page where the pop up is opened. Everytime the pop up opens I need the object to add a **new** key value pair - with the counter number as the key and value as the generated number (made through function getComparitive(), however on console.log I see none of the old key value pairs being saved. Just the current page one. Not sure if my syntax isn't correct. Is it because everytime the pop up opens it reloads and the older key value pairs are deleted?
Any ideas in technique and process would be helpful too.

background.js -

```
let previousUrl = null;
window.visitedSiteCount = 0;

chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function (e) {
 
   if (e.url !== previousUrl) {
      window.visitedSiteCount++;
      previousUrl = e.url;
      console.log(visitedSiteCount)
   }
});
```

pop-up file -

```
let afinn;
let counts = {}
let keys = [];
let graphData = {}
let newParas;
let bgpage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
let siteCount;


function preload() {
   afinn = loadJSON('afinn111.json');
}

function setup() {
   noCanvas();
}

chrome.tabs.query({
   active: true,
   currentWindow: true
}, function (tabs) {

   chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
      greeting: "hello"
   }, function (response) {
      if (response.containsPara === true) {
         newParas = response.text.join(' ');
         getComparitive(newParas)
      }
   });
});

function getComparitive(p) {

   let words = p.replace(/[.,:!]/g, "").split(" ");
   let totalScore = 0;

   for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      let word = words[i].toLowerCase() // since all the words in data set are lowercase!
      if (afinn.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
         let score = afinn[word]
         // check true or false if the the current word is present in dataset
         totalScore += Number(score); // access value of each word in json obj & convert to a number
      }
   }

   siteCount = bgpage.visitedSiteCount;
   let comparitive = totalScore / words.length;
   const comp = select('#comparative');
   comp.html('comparative: ' + comparitive);


   if (graphData[siteCount] === undefined) {
      graphData[siteCount] = comparitive;
   } else {}
}

console.log(graphData);
```

Comment: Yes, the popup is like any other window that shows an html file: it loads when created and terminates when closed. Incidentally, being a separate window, it also has its own separate devtools which can be opened by right-clicking inside the popup and then selecting "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: I see so it basically restarts creating the object?

Comment: Each time it runs the environment is completely new. It's like opening a new tab with a site and then closing it.

Comment: ye ! I see it now, I think I'm going to save my object into local storage so I can keep and not lose it